# Facebook apprequests from page tab - not working as expected

Tags: facebook, tabs, apprequests

Hi I have a Page Tab app, and in it I need to include a Requests Dialog, in order to let users share the page.
I can show the dialog, and the dialog will call me back successfully; but the invited friend sees a new App Request (a +1 in the left column) but he cannot see the detail of the request, just as no requests were received.

My JS code is very simple, copied from one of the samples out there:

```
function sendRequest() {
    FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests', 
                    message: 'Message text.....', 
                    title: 'Title...',
                    data: 'tracking'
                }, 
                function (response) {
                alert(response); 
            }
            );
}
```

What can be wrong? I think that the problem relies on the configuration of the app, but I do not understand what to check.
Any help?

**EDIT**: actually this was a false problem, due to a misconfiguration in the app. The mentioned method works well in a page tab, given that you compile correctly all the fields in app settings, even in the "App on Facebook" section. Even if yours is a "Page Tab".

Comment: "but he cannot see the detail of the request, just as no requests were received." - requests are just titled with message, accept button and little X.

Comment: exactly, there is nothing, no mention of the request.